# Need Sample Leaflet Code to select Current Map View

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

In leaflet Draw I have options for selecting rectangle, polygon etc... However, for one design I need an option where instead of selecting the polygon manually I should be able to select the current map view and do some actions...

Any sample codes will be of great help.

Comment: Could you show any code from what you have tried? SO is meant for helping with coding related issues, it isn't suited for writing code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am able to solve the same by using the command map.getBounds()))  .. This will get the data what i need.

Comment: So you solved your own question?